# How to send a script to a URL with GET using WebView

Tags: android, webview, http-get

I need to send a script to a URL using GET parameters, for example

http://www.url.com/test2.php?actor=14

It is possible to do it with a webview in background without showing it on the screen with this code?

```
        String urlString = "http://www.url.com/test2.php?actor=14";
        this.web=new WebView(this.sc.getContext());
        this.web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.web.loadUrl(urlString);
        return;
```

As you see, the webview is not added on any layout, so it will be transparent to the user.

Is this a good way to achieve it?

Or this will be the best option?

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
  InputStream content = null;
  try {
    String url = "http://www.url.com/test2.php?actor=14";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    content = response.getEntity().getContent();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);
  }
    return content;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: no. You should/can use the HttpClient to achieve this. The WebView was not offered to deal with that usecase. In your case it is a dirty hack :-)

Comment: I edited, please check it